# How to make ContentVersion public using Apex

Tags: apex, contentversion

I want to make a `ContentVersion` record publicly available using Apex.

I know I can get the `DistributionPublicUrl` value from the `ContentDistribution` object.

But I don't know how I should configure the `ContentVersion` so that the `DistributionPublicUrl` is generated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just create an instance of `ContentDistribution` by providing you `ContentVersion` and a `Name`  and then query the `DistributionPublicUrl`.

```
ContentDistribution cdl = new ContentDistribution();
cdl.ContentVersionId = '0680DXXX002RmxQAE';
cdl.Name = 'PublicShare';
insert cdl;

cdl = [SELECT DistributionPublicUrl FROM ContentDistribution WHERE Id = :cdl.Id LIMIT 1];
return cdl.DistributionPublicUrl;
```

Reference:

- [SOAP API Developer Guide: ContentDistribution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdistribution.htm)